# How to multiply int Random by int in C#

Tags: c#, random, console, console-application, multiplication

I've got a little problem - I'm trying to multiply **random** by **int** in console app. And I've got an error:

> Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of Type 'Random' and 'int'

I've tride: `rndAttackPoints = attackPoints` and then

this `int damagePoints = (rndAttackPoints * strenghtPoints1) - defencePoints1;` into

this `int damagePoints = (attackPoints * strenghtPoints1) - defencePoints1;` but this didn't work.

So I'm asking you, do you know how to multiply `Random` by `int` in C#?

```
            //Elf
            int healthPoints1 = 100;
            int defencePoints1 = 3;
            int strenghtPoints1 = 2;

            // Goblin
            int healthPoints2 = 100;
            int defencePoints2 = 5;
            int strenghtPoints2 = 1;

            Random rndAttackPoints = new Random();            
            Console.WriteLine($"You've attacked: {rndAttackPoints.Next(5, 10)} HP");

            int damagePoints = (rndAttackPoints * strenghtPoints1) - defencePoints1;
```

Comment: Hint: You're getting a random value through `rndAttackPoints.Next(5, 10)`, not by converting `rndAttackPoints` to `int`.

Comment: `new Random()` s something that can generate random thing.  `rndAttackPoints.Next(5, 10)` is the way to get the random value you are looking for. Store the result of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the random value in a separate variable and work with that as follow:

```
Random rndAttackPoints = new Random();
int rnd = rndAttackPoints.Next(5, 10);
Console.WriteLine($"You've attacked: {rnd} HP");

int damagePoints = (rnd * strenghtPoints1) - defencePoints1;
```

Comment: thx, that is easier than I thought it is :)